# GCP Bigquery not providing all bad records in the error stream

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

While batch loading data to BigQuery and specifying the max bad records to 5000. The BigQuery error stream provides 5 error records.

When I change the max bad records to 100 and load the same file. The load fails.

If my understanding is correct it means that there are more bad records than I got previously (5 records)  but BigQuery is not logging it on the error stream.

Can anyone explain why this is so?

BigQuery stream error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery's job error stream only provides the initial errors it encounters, it makes no guarantees that it will provide an exhaustive list of all errors.

See the REST reference documentation for more information.  The error stream lives inside the JobStatus submessage:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobstatus

If you want to do more extensive validation of input files, I'd recommend some kind of preprocessing (perhaps something in dataflow/beam), or switch to a better format that's self describing like avro or parquet.  CSV is somewhat of a notorious format due to the many idiosyncrasies and differences among various readers and writers.

Comment: @shollyman- Thanks for answering my question and clearing my doubts. : )